# AEM can i write to the file system from the publish instance

Tags: java, aem

I have a requirement where I need to write a new file to the JCR file system. Sometimes, the request to create this new file originates on the publish server instance. Originally, i was trying to create a page node but was getting permissions issues on the publish instance. is there any way to avoid this permissions issue and have files written from the publish server? (java is being used on the server)

Comment: are you able to share code snippets? your question is a  little vague.

Comment: All anonymous write permissions are disabled by default on a properly confugred publish instance. Have you checked these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're trying to write something with the anonymous user that does not have the proper privileges. You need to run your code with elevated privileges.

In AEM 6.0 and above you should get a `ResourceResolverFactory::getServiceResourceResolver`. This will give a ResourceResolver that is correlated with some user that you need to grant proper rights. The mapping between the 'service' and 'user/group' is done in OSGi configuration.

Alternatively, to check whether this (access rights) is actually your issue it's easier to go with the deprecated `ResourceResolverFactory::getAdministrativeResourceResolver` for which you do not need any configuration changes. I would advise to use it only for checking not for production code.

Then you should get all the necessary util classes via the resourceResolver obtained in this manner.